# Sharing Database Data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

I need to share textual data between 2 users. I'm probably going to use some Android Cloud service (Open to Suggestion) to do so but I'm not sure about a good PK. I didn't want to use DATETIME as the PK but I don't know any other way. What is a good PK to share between 2 (or more) users without much overhead?

If I have in my `SharedTable` 100 entries and my friend only has 2 entries in his `ShareTable` then I would need both his (2) PK and my (101) PK to share any edits to the data between myself, him and anyone else I'm sharing this information with so it seems like auto-incrementing it out of the question.

I can't imagine this isn't a common problem but I can't wrap my head around it so it's hard to get my point across. If you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use uids (unique ids) as your pk, this will guarantee unique entries wherever they are created so combining, updating etc can be done.

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
```

Comment: if I'm picking a random ID isn't there a chance (no matter how small) that it can exist?